# What OpenId plugin/gem shall I use for my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

There are so many plugins/gems but must of them have outdated documentation or no documentation at all.

From what I have seen there are the Rails openid, Eastmedia openid, Authlogic openid, rails kit openid plugins and from a gem search we have rails_openid, pelle-ruby-openid, rack-openid, openid_auth, openid_fu_generator, openid_login_generator, among others.

Those plugins documented in some blog do not work for me on rails 2.3.5/ruby 1.9.1 and I always get stuck at some point. I can install all plugins via gems but the documentation leaves me wondering how these are to be used in my Rails application.

So what would be the best plugin/gem or even better a recent tutorial on how to implement a Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.9.1 application with Restful Open ID authentication? If the plugin/gem supports OpenID/Oauth hybrid would be better as I plan to add OAuth latter to share contents between several of my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is featured on [openid website](http://openid.net/developers/libraries), so it's quite mature:
http://github.com/openid/ruby-openid

It has not working examples, but this railcast provided more than enough information for me:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication

Comment: thanks for answering... now I am using devise that does not supports OpenId but it is a matter of time before it supports it and additionally supports a lot more authentication methods.